MongoDB issue with TLS
I am trying to set up TLS certificates for my standalone MongoDB instance on a cloud compute instance.
I got the certificates from certbot using the command  sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d.
i have then run the following commands:
cat privkey.pem fullchain.pem > /etc/ssl/mongod.pem.
cat chain.pem > /etc/ssl/ca.pem.
I've updated the certificate permissions with:
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/ca.pem
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/mongod.pem

I have updated my /etc/mongod.conf:
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  ssl:
    mode: requireTLS
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongod.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false

Using the command ps aux | grep mongodb i can see that mongodb is running with the user root:
root      134510  0.0  0.0 221432  2060 pts/0    S+   13:28   0:00 grep --color=auto mongodb
However, after i restart the mongod service, it fails to start and when i check the logs i can see the following errors:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-08T13:15:39.573+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23248,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Cannot read certificate file","attr":{"keyFile":"/etc/ssl/mongod.pem","error":"error:FFFFFFFF8000000D:system library::Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-08T13:15:39.573+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":140,"codeName":"InvalidSSLConfiguration","errmsg":"Can not set up PEM key file."}}}

Can someone help me out please ?

i can see that mongodb is running with the user root - it isn't. Your grep is running as root. mongodb is not running at all. find the correct user (systemctl show -P User mongodb) and set the permissions accordingly.

Thank you for that
